# The requested URL /wordpress/ was not found on this server

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu

I am pretty new to wordpress i installed it on my system using this [tutorial](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04/), everything worked and i got my wordpress working, i set up everything and shut down my system. when i restarted my system and visited http://localhost/wordpress/ i got this error
[image]

```
Not Found

The requested URL /wordpress/ was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

After searching the internet for a while i have tried many fixes like going to:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and changing the permissions but non of this worked for me till now.

hoping for a positive response from you guys.

**apache2.conf**

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300


KeepAlive On


MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}


HostnameLookups Off


ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All

</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride All

</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All

</Directory>


<Directory /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/>
    AllowOverride All
  Allow from All

</Directory>






AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>



LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Do you have definition for this directory in `apache2.conf` ?

Comment: Yes i do, i have added apache2.conf, please have a look @RomeoNinov

Comment: Try to add `DocumentRoot` to `Directory` definition for wordpress

Comment: really sorry but i dnot't know how to do that can you please tell me @RomeoNinov

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: @RomeoNinov you deleted your answer?

Comment: Yes, I think it is irrelevant. Sorry

Answer (score 4):

**1)** Created new one by clicking on save button in **Settings->Permalinks**

Click in the field and press **CTRL + a** to select all. Paste on **.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**2)** Now, Need to activate **mod_rewrite**:

**sudo a2enmod rewrite**

This will activate the module or alert you that the module is already in effect. To put these changes into effect, restart Apache:

**sudo service apache2 restart**

and now that pages started working fine...